# Relación uno a muchos diferencia con relacion muchos a muchos

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo un ejemplo donde no termino de entender ¿Cuál es la forma óptima de resolverlo?

Una tabla llamada `usuarios`.

Una tabla llamada `publicaciones`.

Si planeo guardar los registros de una publicación con el `id` del usuario que lo registro; la siguiente estructura es correcta?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero por ejemplo atendiendo a que se pudiera crear una tabla intermedia llamada `publicaciones-usuarios` con una estructura similar a la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál es el modo óptimo?, ya que por ejemplo si hago la primer estructura con un `inner join` como el siguiente:

```
SELECT titulo, cuerpo, username FROM publicaciones
INNER JOIN usuarios
ON usuarios.id = publicaciones.usuarios_id
WHERE usuarios.id = 2;
```

Puedo sacar las publicaciones que haga un usuario teniendo en cuanta que la vinculación de ambas tablas es el `id` del usuario como llave foránea en la tabla `publicaciones`; pero no termino de entender bajo que escenarios se usa cada uno

Es solo un ejemplo atendiendo a que busco aclarar esta duda

Comment: Por lo que dices, no me queda claro si las publicaciones también pueden tener varios usuarios. Si la respuesta a mi pregunta es sí, entonces en mi criterio la opción óptima es la 2da, la que tiene una tercera tabla. No obstante, yo eliminaría la clave primaria que pusiste a la tercera tabla (supongo que sea un auto incremental) y conformaría la clave primaria de esa tercera tabla (publicaciones-usuarios) con la combinación de las dos claves primarias del resto de las tablas, así aseguro que el modelo esté en tercera forma normal y en Boyce-Codd, pues con el auto incremental no está ni en terce

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Las relaciones en sí

La cuestión de fondo para responder a tu pregunta no es *si usando este tipo de relación puedo obtener tales datos, mientras que usando este otro tipo de relación no los puedo obtener*.

Realmente, los datos los puedes obtener igualmente con cualquier tipo de relación, si las mismas están bien planteadas.

En breve podemos decir que:

### La relación uno a muchos

Aplica únicamente cuando :

- una publicación no puede tener más de un usuario .... (*uno a...*)
- un usuario puede tener varias publicaciones  ...............     (*muchos*)

O, al revés:

- un usuario no puede tener más de una publicación .... (*uno a...*)
- una publicación puede tener varios usuarios  ...............     (*muchos*)

---

### La relación muchos a muchos

Aplica cuando:

- una publicación puede tener más de un usuario ........ (*muchos a...*)
- un usuario puede tener varias publicaciones  ...............     (*muchos*)

Dependiendo de cómo esté montada tu aplicación, **basada en la realidad de los datos que maneja**, entonces tendrás que decidir por cual tipo de relación implementar.

O sea ¿cuál es la **realidad** de los datos que va a manejar tu aplicación?:

- ¿un usario, varias publicaciones?  : relación uno (usuarios) a muchos (publicaciones)
- ¿una publicación, varios usuarios? : relación uno (publicaciones) a muchos (usuarios)
- ¿varios usuarios, varias publicaciones? : relación muchos (usuarios) a muchos (publicaciones) implementando una tabla asociativa o de unión (usuarios_publicaciones)

---

## El *modo óptimo*

En cuanto a la manera óptima de hacer las cosas, como ha dicho @gbianchi en su comentario. El modo óptimo es aquel que optimice lo que quieres hacer en la base de datos, cumpliendo las reglas de negocios.

No basta con tener un tipo de relación acorde con la realidad de los datos que manejas. Todavía quedarán cabos sueltos que debes atar en la definición de las tablas, tales como índices para agilizar la obtención de datos, controlar registros duplicados, agregar restricciones de integridad referencial que eviten la existencia de registros huérfanos, etc.

---

## Obtener los datos

Sea cual sea la relación que uses, **siempre** podrás obtener los datos que quieras de las tablas.

Veamos:

### Obteniendo datos en una relación uno a muchos

```
SELECT 
    u.nombre, 
    p.titulo 
FROM usuarios u
INNER JOIN publicaciones p ON u.id_usario = p.id_usuario
```

### Obteniendo datos en una relación muchos a muchos

```
SELECT 
    u.nombre, 
    p.titulo 
FROM usuarios_publicaciones up
INNER JOIN usuarios u ON up.id_usario = u.id_usuario
INNER JOIN publicaciones p ON up.id_publicacion = p.id_publicacion
```

En ambos ejemplos se obtienen las mismas columnas. Lo única que varía es la forma de obtener los datos haciendo los `JOIN` correspondientes, basados en la forma en que hemos creado las relaciones.

**Lo que quiero decir es que no puedes definir una relación pensando que eso tiene alguna implicación en la forma de obtener los datos**. No tiene ninguna implicación. En ambos ejemplos obtenemos las mismas columnas `nombre` de la tabla `usuarios` y `titulo` de la tabla `publicaciones`. Y así, podemos obtener cualquier columna que participe de la relación.

Otra cosa sería el hecho de obtener los datos agrupados, por ejemplo en el caso de las relaciones muchos a muchos. Para eso también existen funciones de agrupación, como `GROUP_CONCAT`, en el caso concreto de MySQL.

Comment: Puedo aclarar que a la pregunta cual es el modo optimo, la respuesta es aquel que optimice lo que queres hacer en la base de datos, y cumpla con las reglas de negocios? porque siempre en estas preguntas, se deja de lado que el modo optimo no es el del libro, si no el que cumpla con lo que se necesita

Comment: @gbianchi respondí a la pregunta tratando de explicar de forma sencilla cuándo aplicaba un tipo de relación u otro, porque se expresaba una dificultad para entender cual usar... En cuanto al *modo óptimo* de hacerlo, creo que sería consecuencia de aplicar el tipo de relación que se requiera, basándose en la realidad de los datos en este caso. En otros casos, sería algo tan amplio, que no habría *un modo óptimo de responder* :)

Comment: Perfecto, pero esa aclaracion siempre se deja de lado.. como si no fuera necesaria.. es como gritarles a los que hacen queries desde paginas, tu codigo es propenso a inyecciones.. deberia ser la contestacion estandar tambien ;) igual tu respuesta me encanto...