# problemas con la llave primaria

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image: este es el modelo relacional]buen dia compañeros tengo un asunto, lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo una base de datos para mi proyecto en MySQL pero tengo un problema, en las tablas pedido y arealogistica en esta area tengo un solo trabajador o persona encargada de esta area y cuando llegan varios pedidos tendria que repetir la llave primaria del area logistica (idAreaLogistica).

esta es la tabla areaLogistica:

```
CREATE TABLE AreaLogistica(idAreaLogistica INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 identificacionEmpleado INT NOT NULL,
 nombreEmpleado VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
 correo VARCHAR(20),
 telefono VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 cumpleaños DATE NOT NULL);
```

esta el tabla pedido:

```
 CREATE TABLE Pedido(codigoPedido INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 fechaPedido DATE NOT NULL,
 descripcionPedido VARCHAR(300),
 fk_idCliente VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (fk_idCliente) REFERENCES Cliente(idCliente));
```

estos serian los datos de la tabla areaLogistica

```
insert into arealogistica(idAreaLogistica, identificacionEmpleado, nombreEmpleado, correo, telefono, cumpleaños, fk_codigoPedido, fk_nit)
values(2,1037890755, 'Jeferson Andres Moreno', 'moreno23@gmail.com', '3105678456', '1998-06-09', 1, '900.017.253-6'),
(2,1037890755, 'Jeferson Andres Moreno', 'moreno23@gmail.com', '3105678456', '1998-06-09', 2, '900.017.253-6'),
(2,1037890755, 'Jeferson Andres Moreno', 'moreno23@gmail.com', '3105678456', '1998-06-09', 3, '900.017.253-6');
```

la relación es de muchos a muchos.
lógicamente me sale el error de que no puedo repetir la llave primaria.

gracias de antemano y disculpen pero apenas estoy empezando en el tema.

Comment: estas incorrecto si como dices la relación es de muchos a muchos debería existir una tercer tabla que alacene las llaves primarias de pedido y area logistica

Comment: además no debes declarar columnas ni con acentos o con ñ

Comment: Hay muchas formas de resolver dicha situacion, y aclarando lo que te dijeron anteriormente:
Una llave primaria puede ser Int, Varchar, date.. etc todo depende de la lógica del negocio, si quieres que sea aunto incrementables alli si seran Int.
La solución practica seria un tabla que almacene los datos de empleados, una que tenga la categoría o departamento, asi en tu tabla pedidido solo pondrias el id del empleado y todos los demas datos de la propia tabla.

Answer (score 2):

> De acuerdo a tu escenario planteado, deberían ser 3 tablas las 2 que
>   se llaman area Logística y Pedido y una tercera que actue como tabla
>   pivote
>
> Cuando haces una foreign key no puedes vincularla con un varchar como
>   tu lo estas haciendo con el campo que declaras en fk_idCliente pues no
>   son del mismo tipo, las primary keys son enteros no varchar
>
> Del mismo modo los campos que declaras como primary key, ya no es
>   necesario indicarles que no sean nulos y si es necesario que le
>   indiques que serán campos auto incrementales

Te hago esta propuesta de solución

```
CREATE TABLE AreaLogistica
(
    idAreaLogistica INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    identificacionEmpleado INT NOT NULL,
    nombreEmpleado VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    correo VARCHAR(20),
    telefono VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    cumpleanios DATE NOT NULL
);

 CREATE TABLE Pedido(
     codigoPedido INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     fechaPedido DATE NOT NULL,
     descripcionPedido VARCHAR(300),
     fk_idCliente INT NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT fk_pedido_cliente FOREIGN KEY (fk_idCliente) REFERENCES Cliente(idCliente) 
 );


 --Esta sería la tabla pivote, bajo el argumento de que tu relación sea verdaderamente de muchos a muchos
 CREATE TABLE logistica_pedido(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fk_idAreaLogistica INT NOT NULL,
    fk_codigoPedido INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_logistica_pedido_AreaLogistica FOREIGN KEY(fk_idAreaLogistica) REFERENCES AreaLogistica(idAreaLogistica),
    CONSTRAINT fk_logistica_pedido_Pedido FOREIGN KEY(fk_codigoPedido) REFERENCES AreaLogistica(codigoPedido)
 );
```

> De este modo en la tabla pivote será donde se puedan repetir las
>   llaves primarias en forma de llaves foráneas de las otras dos tablas;
>   te doy el contexto que me explicaron en este mismo sitio
>
> Relación muchos a muchos
>
> Varios usuarios pueden modificar varios posts

En este enlace te dejo la pregunta que hice en esta misma plataforma y como me ayudaron a comprender un poco mas sobre este tema

[Relacion uno a muchos Relacion muchos a muchos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151051/relaci%C3%B3n-uno-a-muchos-diferencia-con-relacion-muchos-a-muchos)

Te recomendaría replantear tu Base de Datos y sobre las dudas que tengas, hagas lo que yo postear para ir perfeccionando la identificación de entidades y sus relaciones

Comment: gracias una pregunta se perderan los datos del empleado en la nueva tabla?

Comment: lo ideal será que trabajes sobre una copia de tu base de datos , por que como te digo desde que escribes cumpleaños con la ñ ya estas mal además de las otras observaciones que te hago, mejor crea una base de datos de respaldo y trabaja sobre esa para que no comprometas nada

Comment: este link fue de una pregunta que yo hice al respecto y quien me la respondió me dio una amplia respuesta que te recomiendo leer a detalle https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151051/relaci%C3%B3n-uno-a-muchos-diferencia-con-relacion-muchos-a-muchos

Comment: si claro entiendo es que soy principiante en el tema por eso escribí así, pero vamos  aprendiendo.

Comment: claro y no esta mal preguntar por eso mismo yo hice ese post por que tuve muchas dudas, vamos todo esta bien te deseo exito y feliz aprendizaje