# ¿Relación muchos a muchos en phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

¿Como se realiza una relación muchos a muchos en phpMyAdmin?, ¿me podrían ayudar con información o alguna página que diga como se realiza?.

Gracias.

Comment: plantea el escenario que tienes para ayudarte mejor, lee [ask] partiendo de tus tablas podremos ayudarte mejor

Comment: ya que planteas un escenario de muchos a muchos debemos tener 2 tablas relacionadas por una intermedia que guardará sus id de ambas tablas

Comment: @Alfredo siempre me ayudas ajjajajja trate de contactarte para un problema que tenia pero no supe como, por suerte ya lo solucione. Mira digamos que tengo un estudiante que tiene muchos cursos y a su vez los cursos tienen muchos estudiantes.

Comment: coloca lo que lleves intentado de tus tablas, para que la pregunta se mas completa y no corras el riesgo de que te la voten negativo o te la cierren y claro que te ayudo

Comment: Si estas empezando [esto te puede servir como ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151057/29967) para entender cómo funcionan las relaciones.

Comment: @A.Cedano sería válido responderle con un ejemplo para tratar de ayudarle? o me lloverán los regaños?

Comment: @Alfredo si entiendo, pero en phpMyAdmin ¿tendría que hacer la tabla?, o cuando haga la relación se crea automáticamente.

Comment: las relaciones entre las 3 tablas por ejemplo se crean con las FOREIGN KEY al momento de crear las tablas

Comment: @Alfredo creo que el OP debería al menos compartir la estructura de sus tablas. La pregunta tal y como está planteada ahora es muy pobre. Cualquier respuesta sin entender el problema y el contexto es como dar palos de ciego.

Comment: entiendo y comprendido de hecho es lo que le recomendaba al inicio de los comentarios, espero la mejore y con gusto le ayude gracias @A.Cedano

Comment: @RyuuBlack como ya te comentaron agrega tus tablas y de seguro obtendrás una excelente explicación

Comment: @A.Cedano " al menos compartir la estructura de sus tablas" creo que el OP no tiene ninguna tabla, y a lo que realmente se refiere es al concepto en si y como se ejecuta o funciona este

Comment: @RyuuBlack  [Aqui](http://www.marcossarmiento.com/2017/05/05/como-crear-relaciones-entre-tablas-en-mysql-con-workbench/) tienes informacion de los diferentes tipos de relaciones, entre ellos muchos a muchos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una vez que tienes Creadas las tablas y puestas la calves primarias, en Extructura justo abajo, vienen extructura de tabla y vista de relaciones, en vista de relaciones tendrias que insertar la relacion, diciendo nombre de la relacion ,el campo que quieres relacionar, con que base de datos, tabla y campo de tabla. y te saldra la relacion [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Una relación de muchos a muchos en MySQL o phpMyAdmin **es básicamente una tabla en donde se insertan las referencias de dos o mas tablas sin restricciones.**

Es decir; si tienes una tabla de alumnos y una de clases obviamente vas a tener muchos alumnos y muchas clases. Entonces, cada alumno puede estar relacionado a muchas clases y cada clase puede estar relacionada a muchos alumnos.

Entonces; en una tabla "alumnos_clases" por ejemplo agregas tantos registros como quieras donde los datos son el id del alumno y el id de la clase, cuidando solo el detalle de no repetir registros iguales ya que eso sería duplicidad de datos.

Finalmente, tendrás una tabla donde están relacionados muchos alumnos a muchas clases y puedes de ahí obtener cuantos alumnos están inscritos en una clase o cuantas clases tiene asignadas un alumno.

Todo esto lo puedes hacer en phpMyAdmin.
Espero haber ayudado!!!