# ¿relación 1 a 1 igual a relación muchos a muchos?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, relaciones

Según me dijeron que la relación de 1 a 1 se podría considerar como muchos a muchos y por ende se crearía una tabla intermedia. Eso es cierto ?

Algo así como :

- auto
- conductor

habría otra tabla intermedia que seria

- auto_conductor.

Comment: En tu ejemplo de auto conductor si es relación uno a uno o muchos a muchos depende de las reglas del dominio. Si a un conductor se le asigna un solo auto y el auto será conducido solo por ese conductor la relación será uno a uno. Si varios conductores pueden conducir varios autos será muchos a muchos. Uno a uno no puede considerarse muchos a muchos, el dominio decide qué relación existirá.

Comment: La relación 1 a 1 implica que el registro `A` sólo se  relaciona con el registro  `B` y viceversa. Un ejemplo es el matrimonio: un esposo para una esposa y viceversa. La relación muchos a muchos significa que un `auto` puede tener muchos `conductores` y viceversa. En ese caso la relación se expresa en una tercera tabla pivote o asociativa. Y hay una relación uno a muchos: el conductor `X` puede conducir los autos `X1, X2, X3` pero el conductor `Y` no puede conducir esos autos. [Ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/151051/29967) donde se explica con más detalle.

Comment: Entonces  ¿pudieramos marcar la pregunta como duplicada @A.Cedano?

Comment: @Aprendiz quizá sí, sólo que allí no se trata sobre la relación 1 a 1. Aunque es la relación más fácil de entender, con el ejemplo del matrimonio. Lo raro es que se le haya dicho que una relación 1 a 1 es lo mismo que una relación muchos a muchos cuando son extremos contrarios.

Comment: Te lo preguntaba @A.Cedano por que es una excelente respuesta la que ya esta dada, pero iba a tratar de responder esta

Comment: @Aprendiz quizá sean relacionadas, pero no duplicadas. Realmente la pregunta es *si las relaciones muchos a muchos son iguales a las relaciones 1 a 1*. Una eventual respuesta tendría que aclarar ese punto indicando si son iguales o no y por qué sí lo son o no lo son. Creo que ambas preguntas son complementarias. Aquí no se trata el tema de la relación uno a muchos por ejemplo (no se pregunta por ella).

Comment: He visto que cuando crean usuarios y roles hay una tabla intermedia. Eso quiere decir que muchos usuarios tienen muchos roles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La relación 1 a 1.**

Indica que el registro de la tabla de la izquierda (una llave foránea) solo este relacionada con un registro de la tabla de la derecha, conviene aclarar que a nivel de SQL para limitar que la llave foránea sea única lo podemos hacer a través de un constraint de tipo `UNIQUE`.

Pudiendose ver de este modo en tu propio ejemplo

```
Vehiculos
id
marca
....
....
usuario_id UNIQUE
```

**Ejemplo**

```
Usuario 1----maneja-----1 Vehiculo
```

**En la relación de muchos a muchos.**

Donde:

- Al menos existen 3 tablas relacionadas
- la de medio la tabla pivote almacenará N cantidad de veces las llaves foráneas que la unen o vinculan con las otras 2 tablas.

Que se vería de este modo:
La tabla de usuarios

```
Usuario
id
nombre
.....
.....
```

La tabla de vehiculos

```
Vehiculos
id
modelo
.....
.....
```

La tabla pivote que se pudiera llamar

```
usuarios_vehiculos
id
usuario_id   FK
vehiculo_id  FK
```

> Entonces no no se pueden considerar que funcionan para lo mismo, en este punto sugiero revisar las formas de normalización<sup>1</sup>

Por ejemplo para tu escenario.

- Sería una relación de 1 a 1 cuando el vehículo tiene 1 solo dueño que en teoría es el que lo conduce y solamente el.
- Sería una relación de muchos a muchos cuando por ejemplo se trata de una agencia de taxis donde muchos choferes pueden manejar muchos taxis.

Ahora si tu escenario (**ya que la respuesta de que relación usar depende de lo que tratas de resolver, aunque no por eso quiere decir que son lo mismo**), un chofer solo puede manejar un vehículo entonces es relación 1 a 1 hasta donde entiendo no hay razón para que exista una tercera tabla que las vinvule.

**Enlaces de interés**

- <sup>1</sup> [normalización](https://support.microsoft.com/es-mx/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics)
- [relaciones en SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15)

En especial recomiendo [esta respuesta de A.Cedano que complementa muchísimo este pobre aporte](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151051/relaci%c3%b3n-uno-a-muchos-diferencia-con-relacion-muchos-a-muchos)

Comment: muchas gracias, pero todavia tengo una duda con la FK, que tabla es la que da  su pk como fk ?

Comment: @makoto como tal esa duda se sale del contexto de tu pregunta, dado eso te recomiendo busques sobre el tema de cardinalidad en las bases de datos relacionales