# ¿Cómo establecer relación 1:n en base de datos SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Mi pregunta es sencilla de formular pero parece que complicada de ejecutar; he estado buscando y no encuentro nada similar para solucionar mi problema.

Tengo esta base de datos que acabo de crear, pero tengo un problema: a la hora de relacionar las categorías y las películas/series que de esto va esta base de datos, es decir... ¿como puedo hacer para relacionar una película a varias categorías?

Con el diseño de base de datos actual solo podría relacionar 1 a 1.

```html
CREATE DATABASE torrentmartia;
USE torrentmartia;

CREATE TABLE usuarios(

    id                  INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    usuario             VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    clave               VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    rango               VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(id)

)ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE categorias(

    id                  INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre              VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(id)

)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE entradas(

    id                  INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    titulo              VARCHAR(100),
    img                 VARCHAR(100),
    url_descarga        VARCHAR(200),
    veces_descargada    INT(11),
    categoria           INT(11),

    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(categoria) REFERENCES categorias(id)

)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: ¿Y dónde esta la tabla películas?, además ¿por qué asumes que solo permite de 1 a 1?

Comment: Es simple, tendrías que crear una tabla `pelicula_categoria` con las columnas `id_pelicula,id_categoria` donde expresarás el tipo de relación para este tipo que es muchos a muchos. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151057/29967) he abundado sobre el tema con algunos ejemplos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitarás una tabla intermedia (Yo la conozco como tabla pivote)

```sql
CREATE DATABASE torrentmartia;
USE torrentmartia;

CREATE TABLE usuarios(

    id                  INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    usuario             VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    clave               VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    rango               VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(id)

)ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE categorias(

    id                  INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre              VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(id)

)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE entradas(

    id                  INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    titulo              VARCHAR(100),
    img                 VARCHAR(100),
    url_descarga        VARCHAR(200),
    veces_descargada    INT(11),
    categoria           INT(11),

    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(categoria) REFERENCES categorias(id)

)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE categorias_entradas(

    id                  INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    categoria           INT(11) NOT NULL,
    entrada             INT(11) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(categoria) REFERENCES categorias(id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(entrada) REFERENCES entradas(id)

)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

En ella podrás insertar cada una de las "entradas" con cada una de las "categorías".