# ¿Como asignar correctamente la clave foranea?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo un poco de lio con este tema me han pedido que haga una entidad relación entre 3 tablas, la tabla usuarios, la tabla ventas y la tabla noticias, un usuario puede crear muchas ventas y muchas noticias, es decir que será una relación de 1 a muchos entre usuarios y las otras dos tablas. El problema que tengo ahora es que no se muy bien como colocar la clave foránea de forma correcta. Necesito utilizar el nombre del usuario para colocarlo como autor de noticias y ventas que ha creado. Pero nose como unirlo si mediante un id desde la tabla de usuarios que haga referencia a ventas y a noticias, o debo colocar el nombre de usuario como clave foránea?

dejo por aqui las tablas que tengo hechas:

```
Tabla usuarios    

[PK]+id - bigint(20)
+name - varchar(255)
+surname - varchar(255)
+email - varchar(255)
+created_at - timestamp
+updated_at - timestamp

Tabla ventas

[PK]+id - bigint(20)
+titulo - varchar(255)
+autor - varchar(255) --> esto es lo que me gustaría enlazar con usuarios
+precio - int(11)
+nombre_vendedor - varchar(255)
+contacto_vendedor - varchar(255)
+detail - text
+image - varchar(255)
+created_at - timestamp
+updated_at - timestamp

Tabla noticias

[PK]+id - bigint(20)
+titulo -  varchar(255)
+autor - varchar(255) --> esto es lo que me gustaría enlazar con usuarios
+detail - text
+image - varchar(255)
+created_at - timestamp
+updated_at - timestamp
```

Alguna idea??  Gracias!!!

Comment: Si cada `venta` y cada `noticia` pertenece a un usuario en exclusiva, lo que tienes que hacer es poner la columna `id` de la tabla `usuarios` en `venta` y en `noticia`, y esa columna sería llave foránea en ambas tablas. Si por el contrario una `venta` o `noticia` puede pertencer a varios `usuarios` tendrías que expresar la relación en una tercera tabla asociativa. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151057/29967) que podría arrojar un poco más de luz al respecto.

Comment: Decididamente el nombre del usuario no es una buena idea, es fácil encontrar nombres relativamente comunes con los mismos apellidos.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Pablo y jachguate, el nombre del usuario no debería ser clave ni único en la tabla USUARIOS y por tanto no podría declararse como clave foránea desde VENTAS ni NOTICIAS. Donde pones autor en estas dos últimas tablas deberías poner idUsuario y restringirlo como clave foranea al id de la tabla USUARIOS, como indica jachguate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar cualquier campo o combinación de campos de una tabla para crear una llave foránea hacia ella, siempre que se cumpla con los requisitos siguientes:

- Los campos no pueden contener valores nulos (deben ser `not null`).
- El campo o campos debe poder identificar a uno y solo uno de los registros de la tabla. A esto se le llama *identificar de manera unívoca*.

  En otras palabras, si no es la llave primaria, debe existir un constraint `unique` sobre los campos; algunos motores también soportan que haya un índice único sobre los mismos.

  Esto también significa que no puedes tener dos registros que tengan el mismo valor, cosa que tiene sentido, pues si esto ocurriera, el motor no podría determinar a cual de esos dos registros está asociado un registro de otra tabla bajo la llave foránea.

Dicho esto, lo más común y natural es que la llave foránea se haga hacia el campo o campos de la llave primaria de una tabla, que ya cumplen esas condiciones. Luego puedes obtener cualquier dato que necesites del registro asociado haciendo un *join* entre las tablas, eso no suele ser problema.

Entonces, si decides dejar el campo `autor` de las tablas noticias y ventas, supongo que lo asociarías al campo `name` de la tabla de `usuarios`, por lo que debes comenzar por asegurarte que la columna sea `not null` y crear un constraint `unique` sobre dicho campo:

```
alter table usuarios 
  add constraint UQ_Usuarios_Name 
  unique (name);
```

Ahora, puedes ya declarar la llave foránea, por ejemplo en `ventas`:

```
alter table ventas 
  add constraint fk_ventas_usuarios 
  foreign key (autor)
  references usuarios (name);
```

Yo desaconsejo esta práctica. En mi opinión, debes tener una muy buena razón para hacer una llave foránea a un campo que no es la llave primaria de una tabla.

Obviamente, si decides usar la llave primaria, tendrás que cambiar el campo en las tablas de ventas y noticias, por ejemplo, agregando un campo nuevo y eliminando el anterior:

```
alter table ventas 
  add idUsuario bigint;

alter table ventas 
  add constraint fk_ventas_usuarios 
  foreign key (idUsuario)
  references usuarios (id);

alter table ventas 
  drop column autor;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! finalmente he optado por añadir idUsuario a ventas y idUsuario a noticias que va enlazado con el id de usuario, esto es correcto si no he entendido mas cierto?

Comment: Si, es correcto :)