# Un metodo de guardado que me genere un numero de orden para varios pedidos?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

tengo un formulario con input dinámicos para insertar varios productos, cree una tabla con un campo llamado nro de orden el cual es autoincrementado, estoy buscando la manera de que un pedido con varios producto se guarde con el mismo numero de orden ya que al llegar todos los productos me genera un nro de orden diferente, se puede realizar esto de manera no manual ?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Declara la columna `nro_orden` de tipo `AUTO_INCREMENT`. [Revisa el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) para ver cómo funciona y cómo se define.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo hice con el AUTO_INCREMENT y me muestra lo que mande en la imagen de arriba, me toma los productos como ordenes diferentes ,estaba buscando la manera para no tener que meter ese dato manual.

Comment: Perdona, no leí bien la pregunta. Es justo lo contrario de lo dicho en mi anterior comentario, debes declarar la columna del tipo `INT` y al hacer la inserción le pasas el `nro_orden` en cada producto. Se supone que tienes otra tabla que guarda de manera única cada orden.

Comment: @A. Cedano pues en realidad lo que quiero es que las ordenes se generen de manera automatica al guardar el pedido por eso pense en el AUTO_INCREMENT  
pero no contaba con que si guardaba varios productos este generaria otro numero de orden para la tabla pedido

Comment: Claro, y así debe ser. Lo propio sería tener las ordenes en **otra tabla**, donde cada orden tendrá una sola fila (en esa tabla el `nro_orden`  será `auto_increment`), y tendrá **otras columnas** como la fecha, el cliente, etc. Y en las otras tablas donde necesites expresar relaciones con las ordenes pongas únicamente el `nro_orden` (pero en esas otras tablas ya no será `auto_increment`) porque puede haber más de una fila con ese `nro_orden`

Comment: [Creo que esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151057/29967) puede aclararte algunos aspectos sobre las relaciones entre tablas que conviene comprender al principio, para no cometer errores en el diseño. Aquí necesitarás al menos dos tablas, si quieres tener un modelo de datos normalizado, sin redundancia y fácil de mantener.

Comment: @A. Cedano Listo hare de esa forma, muchas gracias