# Como retornar un arreglo que contenga un nuevo campo para identificar un usuario suscrito en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

¡¡¡Saludos comunidad!!!

Estoy atascado en como general una consulta a dos tablas y retornar un arreglo que contenga un nuevo campo para identificar un usuario suscrito a un evento.
Hasta ahora, la solución que se me ocurrió fue esta:

```
    public function UserList($uID = NULL){
        if(!is_null($uID) AND !is_numeric($uID)){
            Alerts::Alert(401);
            die;
        }

        $query = "SELECT code, name, resum, date, cost, img FROM _events JOIN  _events_subscribers 
                        WHERE _events_subscribers.member_id = :uID AND _events_subscribers.event_code = _events.code";

        $stmt = self::conn()->prepare($query);
        if(!is_null($uID) AND is_numeric($uID)){
            $stmt->bindParam(':uID', $uID);
        }
        
        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            Logs::Server('MySQL Error: "'.implode(' >> ', $stmt->errorInfo()).'", on Lib_Events->UserList()');
            Alerts::Alert('MySQL', 'Lib_Events()->UserList()');
            die;
        }
        
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            $myList = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $all = $this->List(NULL, false);
            for($i = 0; $i <= count($myList); $i++){
                $all[$i]->sub = 0;
                if(isset($all[$i]->code) AND isset($myList[$i]->code)){
                    if(($all[$i]->code == $myList[$i]->code)){
                        $all[$i]->sub = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            Response::json($all);
            exit();
        }
        
        Alerts::Alert(404, 'Lib_Events()->UserList()');
        exit();
    }
```

La idea es, que al procesar la respuesta json, cada elemento contenga el campo sub para poder diferencia en el frontend y decidir que mostrar.

Gracias por leer.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar el problema? Leí la pregunta y el código, y no entendí qué significa: *retornar un arreglo que contenga un nuevo campo para identificar un usuario suscrito en MySQL*. Explica además lo que hace tu código: ¿da error? ¿qué error? ¿qué esperas obtener y qué obtienes?

Comment: Supongamos que en la tabla _events tengo los campos id, name, cost, etc y en otra _events_subscribers tengo event_code y member_id, quiero hacer un select de _events que me traiga todos los eventos y poder unir con _events_subscribers, si se encuentra el id de usuario logeado en la tabla _events_subscribers.

La idea es usar este valor, para mostrar información personalizada en el frontend.

Comment: Eso lo puedes hacer con `JOIN` (ver [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)). Revisa las consultas de ejemplo al final de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151057/29967) que muestran cómo podrías unir dos o más tablas.