# ¿Es válido definir llaves foráneas en círculo con 2 tablas? MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo 2 tablas: `usuarios`, `productos`.

```
usuarios:
   - id
   - nombre
   - foreign key(id_productos)
```

```
productos:
   - id
   - nombre
   - foreign key(id_usuarios)
```

Mi lógica es la siguiente: 1 usuario puede publicar muchos productos. No sé si a la inversa estoy bien pero pienso: **muchos productos pueden ser publicados por 1 usuario**.

La razón de la definición de las foráneas en ambas tablas es para que al publicar un producto, se guarde la identificación del usuario que lo publicó. En `usuarios` la foránea tiene como objetivo almacenar la identificación del producto publicado por X usuario. ¿Estoy bien con esa lógica?

Comment: No hace falta al foreing que esta en usuario, al ponerla sobre producto estas definiendo que un usuario puede tener muchos productos. aunque puedes definirla tal como dices, esa key en usuarios solo seria relacion 1 a 1

Comment: Yo pensaba definirla en ```usuarios``` porque consideraba más fácil el reconocimiento de todos los productos que el usuario ha publicado pero ahora que lo analizo mejor, como que no tiene mucho sentido si tengo la intención que el usuario publique muchos productos :/

Comment: `usuarios -> productos_x_usuario <- productos`, me parece mas acorde a una aplicación tradicional donde usuarios comparten la publicacion de productos, si cada producto sólo pertenece a un usuario sería `usuarios <- productos` onda `select * from productos where user_id=xx` las constrains en la foreign key te ayudan con el tema de por ejemplo borrar todos los productos al borrar el usuario referenciado eso lo hace la db automágicamente

Comment: Según lo expuesto en la pregunta, parece que necesitas una relación *muchos a muchos* expresada en una tabla asociativa `usuarios_productos` donde cada id de usario se relacione con su(s) respectivo(s) producto(s). Quizá [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151057/29967) pueda arrojar un poco más de luz al respecto.

Comment: No veo problemas en tu lógica si por ejemplo necesitas un reporte de la tabla productos con todos los productos ingresados por un usuario determinado, guardar ese dato en la tabla producto o en una tabla terciaria, solo dependerá de como definas tu base.

Comment: Al final he optado por la opción de una tabla asociativa que almacene los identificadores de ```usuarios``` y ```productos```. ¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda!