# funcion identificar usuario una vez haya iniciado sesión PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy intentando crear una función para identificar un usuario antes de procesar una comprar y que luego de registrarse e iniciar sesión el carrito se mantenga y se actualice a el id del usuario y si el usuario cierra sesión nuevamente también se mantenga el carrito.

me podrían dar una idea por favor??
Un saludo

```
function GetIdCarrito(){
// Verificamos si la session ya no esta iniciada
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

// Verificamos si el usuario esta logeado
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario']))
    return $_SESSION['usuario']['id'];      
    

// verificamos si la cookie temporal ya existe y si es asi sera su identificador
elseif (isset($_COOKIE['TiendaDetallesCarrito']))
    return $_COOKIE['TiendaDetallesCarrito'];
else {
// sino es que es la primera vez q el usuario ingresa a la web
// por lo tanto no hay producto en el carrito y generamos un identificador unico aleatoio, 
// creara la cookie y devolvera el identificado unico.
    $tempCarrito = uniqid(rand(), 1);
    setcookie('TiendaDetallesCarrito', $tempCarrito);
    return $tempCarrito;
}
```

}

Comment: Lo mejor sería persistir la información en una base de datos.

Comment: Gracias, lo registre a la base de datos como temporal y cuando hizo el login, actualice el id del carrito, pero ahora me sale Duplicate entry '39' for key 'PRIMARY', cuando confirmo el pedido a ver que sera, un saludo

Comment: El error *Duplicate entry '39' for key 'PRIMARY',* significa que declaraste la columna `id` como llave primaria, por tanto, en esa tabla no debe haber más de una fila con el mismo valor (`39` en este caso). Por lo general se crean varias tablas, por poner un ejemplo, una tabla `cliente` en la cual el id es único y otra tabla `compra` donde el `id` de cliente puede repetirse en varias filas, porque un mismo cliente **puede hacer varias compras**. Conviene que revises las relaciones entre tablas. Ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151057/29967) por ejemplo.